# Get frame of View inside UIViewController with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller, which has a `UINavigationController`, and a `UITabController` attached.

I'd like to know if there's a way to get the available screen space? I'd really like to be to say `CGPoint(0,0);` is definitely in the top left corner, just below the `UINavigationController` and that `self.view.frame.size.height` is only the space I have left to draw in.

I've tried:
`self.view.bounds` and `self.view.frame`, but both think that the available space is 320x460, not 320x367 as I'd expect.

What would be the most correct way to do this, aside from hard-coding the number?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this methods? Did you try in `viewDidAppear` already?

Comment: Sorry - I'm calling them in `viewDidLoad`. Yes - `viewWillAppear` works. Please could you answer the question with this so I can mark it?

Comment: So call in viewDidAppear and post what you get.

Comment: I tried `CGSize bounds = self.view.bounds.size;` in `viewDidAppear` and get the result I was expecting 320x367. Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to log the bounds in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, you will get the expected result.